# How to two select statements with sum functions in them

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I'm trying to join these two tables and I get an error when I use any join. Union will work but returns all the values in two rows as opposed to 3 which I need. This is what I have so far and what it returns is below it. Any help would be great :)

```
select C.CustId ,SUM(Ia.Amount) as total
from Invoice I 
    inner join InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  on I.GUIDInvoice=Ia.GUIDInvoice
    inner join Customer C on  C.GUIDCustomer=I.GUIDCustomer
WHERE DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate()))
and DATEPART(yyyy, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(yyyy, -0, getdate()))
group by C.CustId
union
select C.CustId ,SUM(Ia.Amount) as total2
from Invoice I 
    inner join InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  on I.GUIDInvoice=Ia.GUIDInvoice
    inner join Customer C on  C.GUIDCustomer=I.GUIDCustomer
WHERE DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -2, getdate()))
and DATEPART(yyyy, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(yyyy, -0, getdate()))
group by C.CustId
```

The returned result is below with the required result below that

```
Custid        total
a             2
b             9
b             12
c             16
d             3
d             12

Custid        total      total2
a             2         
b             9          12
c             16
d             3          12
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Neither `MySQL` nor `SQLite` support `DATEPART`. Are you using `SQL Server 2008`?

Comment: What error are you getting when using the `JOIN`?  The `UNION` will not achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.custid, c.total, c2.total2
from (select C.CustId ,SUM(Ia.Amount) as total
  from Invoice I 
      inner join InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  on I.GUIDInvoice=Ia.GUIDInvoice
      inner join Customer C on  C.GUIDCustomer=I.GUIDCustomer
  WHERE DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate()))
  and DATEPART(yyyy, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(yyyy, -0, getdate()))
  group by C.CustId) c
 inner join
  (select C.CustId ,SUM(Ia.Amount) as total2
  from Invoice I 
      inner join InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  on I.GUIDInvoice=Ia.GUIDInvoice
      inner join Customer C on  C.GUIDCustomer=I.GUIDCustomer
  WHERE DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -2, getdate()))
  and DATEPART(yyyy, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(yyyy, -0, getdate()))
  group by C.CustId) c2 on c.custid = c2.custid
```

Comment: This seemed to have worked perfectly I can see where I was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to have 2 columns of SUM of different Months. Here is what you can do:

```
Select C.CustId ,
Sum(Case DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) 
When  DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate())) Then Ia.Amount 
Else 0 End) As 'Total1',
Sum(Case DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) 
When  DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -2, getdate())) Then Ia.Amount 
Else 0 End) As 'Total2'
from Invoice I 
    inner join InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  on I.GUIDInvoice=Ia.GUIDInvoice
    inner join Customer C on  C.GUIDCustomer=I.GUIDCustomer
WHERE 
 DATEPART(yyyy, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(yyyy, -0, getdate()))
group by C.CustId
```

I am using Case to avoid the recursive join.

Comment: good start, but the group by is expecting aggregations.  You will then lose final expectations.  I think you need to do SUM( case/when ) Total1 and SUM( case/when ) Total2

Comment: Thanks for that it got the sum of the two column perfectly the only problem is when the months fall over a year end they return zero due to the year always being 2013. when I add this to it it returns 0 due to it looking for 4 months ago from April but the year 2013               Sum(Case DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) 
When  DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -4, getdate())) Then Ia.Amount 
Else 0 End) As 'Total-4',

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL, I would approach by implementing in-line sqlvariables (via my first "from" alias.  The @FirstOfThisMonth is computed by subtracting whatever the current day of month is from the current date (less 1).

Ex: Today is April 3rd (3rd day of month).  So, -3 = March 31... PLUS 1 brings back to April 1 of current month.  Once that date is determined, I can now subtract an entire month for first of PREVIOUS month (March 1st), and subtract 2 months for Feb 1st.

Now that this complexity is done ONCE, we can use these variables instead of constant datepart extraction for month and year.  Especially if you consider trying to do two months ago from Feb 10th.  (First of current is Feb 1, one month back is Jan 1, two months back is Dec 1 of prior year).

NOW, I simply SUM() based on a case when condition.

if the Invoice Date is >= @TwoMonthsAgo AND LESS THAN @LastMonth, that goes into the two-months-ago total.
the next is Invoice Date >= @LastMonth AND LESS THAN @FirstOfThisMonth for last month's total.

Now, you have a rolling two-month window... If you wanted to go longer, just add another monthly variable reference and SUM() its criteria.

Finally the WHERE clause can only include invoices that are greater or equal to the @TwoMonthsAgo so it doesn't have to go through the entire database

```
select 
      C.CustId,
      SUM( CASE when I.InvoiceDate >= @TwoMonthsAgo AND I.InvoiceDate < @LastMonth
           then Ia.Amount else 0 end ) as TotalTwoMonthsAgo,
      SUM( CASE when I.InvoiceDate >= @LastMonth AND I.InvoiceDate < @FirstOfThisMonth
           then Ia.Amount else 0 end ) as TotalLastMonth
   from 
      ( select @FirstOfThisMonth := date_add( now(), INTERVAL -dayofmonth(now())+1 day ),
               @LastMonth := date_add( @myDate, INTERVAL -1 month ),
               @TwoMonthsAgo := date_add( @myDate, INTERVAL -2 month )) sqlvars,
      Invoice I 
         inner join InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  
            on I.GUIDInvoice = Ia.GUIDInvoice
         inner join Customer C 
            on  C.GUIDCustomer = I.GUIDCustomer
   WHERE 
          I.InvoiceDate >= @TwoMonthsAgo
      AND I.InvoiceDate < @FirstOfThisMonth
   group by 
      C.CustID
```